# rmt_storage keeps polling and spam logcat

Tags: kernel, system, logging

In logcat I can see rmt_storage keeps doing something every 2/3 seconds

```
I/rmt_storage(15279): rmt_storage open success
I/rmt_storage(15279): rmt_storage shared memory ioctl success
I/rmt_storage(15279): rmt_storage mmap addr = 40009000
E/rmt_storage(15279): rmt_storage wait event ioctl failed
I/rmt_storage(15280): rmt_storage user app start
I/rmt_storage(15280): rmt_storage open success
I/rmt_storage(15280): rmt_storage shared memory ioctl success
I/rmt_storage(15280): rmt_storage mmap addr = 40009000
E/rmt_storage(15280): rmt_storage wait event ioctl failed
```

It seems like the process rmt_storaeg is spawned again and again and has some failure.

Id like to know WHAT is rmt_storage. 
what are the consequences of stopping it and why does it keeps polling something even when the device is totally idle and the screen is off.

Comment: Something to do with the modem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the Android build as near as we can figure.  If your device is rooted there's a workaround otherwise have fun charging your tablet every single night.  Check out this [Google Groups thread about it](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/nexus/AiQIc2DX5SI/goZA7XvBtUYJ).

On my Galaxy S4 I stopped the service and everything still worked.  However I found that after disabling wifi, I was unable to enable it again until I rebooted, even after restarting the service.  Obviously this is not the case with the Nexus 7 2013, but that does confirm that it's "modem" related.

However I've found several other threads online that reference this service as having to do with external SD Cards (in some ROM development threads) but I do know that with it stopped my S4 wasn't able to toggle the wifi state anymore.